# Pegar o retorno de um AlertDialog para tratar willpopscope

Tags: flutter, alertdialog

tenho uma função chamada showAlertDialogSimNao() e esta recebe o parametro de titulo e conteudo. Gostaria de pegar o retorno desta função e tratar no encerramento do aplicativo. Porem não estou conseguindo. A chamada da função ela acontece porem a função já dá o retorno sem mesmo o usuário ter escolhido a opção "SIM" ou "NAO" para encerrar o aplicativo.

Segue os código:

```
    main.dart

        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:flutter_app01/principal.dart';

        import 'biblioteca.dart';

        void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
            theme: ThemeData.dark(),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: GestaoComercial()));

        class GestaoComercial extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          _GestaoComercialState createState() => _GestaoComercialState();
        }

        class _GestaoComercialState extends State<GestaoComercial> {
          TextEditingController _loginEditingController = TextEditingController(text: 'usuario');
          TextEditingController _pwdEditingController = TextEditingController(text: 'senha');

          bool _loading = false;



          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Gestão Comercial"),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),


              body: Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),

                  Text(
                    'Autenticação',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),

                  TextFormField(
                      controller: _loginEditingController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Identificação",
                        icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                      )),


                  TextFormField(
                      obscureText: true,
                      controller: _pwdEditingController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Senha", icon: Icon(Icons.lock))),


                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),


                  RaisedButton(
                    child: _loading
                        ? linearProgressIndicator(context)
                        : Text("Autenticar"),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        _loading = true;
                      });
                      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
                          Navigator.push(context, SlideRightRoute(page: Principal()));

                      setState(() {
                        _loading = false;
                      });
                    },
                    shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }


biblioteca.dart

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget linearProgressIndicator(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      width: 45.0,
      height: 45.0,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
          strokeWidth: 3.0));
}

class SlideRightRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;

  SlideRightRoute({this.page})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              page,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(-1, 0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
}



bool showAlertDialogSimNao(BuildContext context, String titulo, String conteudo) {
  // configura o button

  Widget btnSim = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Sim"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
    },
  );


  Widget btnNao = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Não"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop(context,false);
    },
  );

  // configura o  AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alerta = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("$titulo"),
    content: Text("$conteudo"),
    actions: [
      btnSim,
      btnNao
    ],
  );
  // exibe o dialog
  showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: ( context )  => alerta);


}



principal.dart

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'biblioteca.dart';

class Principal extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PrincipalState createState() => _PrincipalState();
}

class _PrincipalState extends State<Principal> {


  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    var resposta = showAlertDialogSimNao(
        context, "Encerrar Aplicativo", "Deseja encerrar?");

    print(resposta);
    return resposta;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            leading: Text("AÇÃO 1"),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("APLICATIVO - MODELO"),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
                  return ChoiceCard(choice: choices[index]);
                })),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.green[900],
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              choice.icon,
              color: textStyle.color,
              size: 50.0,
            ),
            Text(
              choice.title,
              style: textStyle,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Venda', icon: Icons.attach_money),
  const Choice(title: 'Cliente', icon: Icons.people),
  const Choice(title: 'Produto', icon: Icons.wallpaper),
  const Choice(title: 'Venda', icon: Icons.monetization_on),
  const Choice(title: 'Cliente', icon: Icons.people),
  const Choice(title: 'Produto', icon: Icons.wallpaper),
  const Choice(title: 'Venda', icon: Icons.monetization_on),
  const Choice(title: 'Cliente', icon: Icons.people),
  const Choice(title: 'Produto', icon: Icons.wallpaper),
  const Choice(title: 'Venda', icon: Icons.monetization_on),
  const Choice(title: 'Cliente', icon: Icons.people),
  const Choice(title: 'Produto', icon: Icons.wallpaper),
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tendo problemas em trabalhar com processos assíncronos, as alterações abaixo provavelmente irão resolver seu problema...

Modifique seu método `showAlertDialogSimNao()` para torná-lo assíncrono

```
Future<bool> showAlertDialogSimNao(BuildContext context, String titulo, String conteudo) async{
  // configura o button

  Widget btnSim = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Sim"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
    },
  );


  Widget btnNao = FlatButton(
    child: Text("Não"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pop(context,false);
    },
  );

  // configura o  AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alerta = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("$titulo"),
    content: Text("$conteudo"),
    actions: [
      btnSim,
      btnNao
    ],
  );

  // exibe o dialog
  return = await showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: ( context )  => alerta);

}
```

E então modifique o método `_onWillPop()` também para funcionar corretamente, pois você está utilizando ele de forma assíncrona, mas o mesmo não possuí nada assíncrono

```
Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
   resposta = await showAlertDialogSimNao(
    context, "Encerrar Aplicativo", "Deseja encerrar?");

  print(resposta);
  return resposta;
}
```

*No momento estou sem acesso ao Flutter para testar, talvez você precise ajeitar uma coisinha aqui ou ali no meu exemplo.*

Comment: Legal Matheus.. realmente o problema era referente a Sincronização.  Valeu. Deu certo.

Comment: @FernandoCasagrande se resolveu se problema e você não quiser aguardar outra resposta, marque a minha como aceita para facilitar pra quem tiver problemas parecidos! E bom dev ai!